# Card.io usage in android. Displaying Credit card number and Expiry date

Tags: android

I am doing an android app, app reads the 16 digit credit card number and Expiry date and display it. For that I'm using Card.io. 
app scans the card continuously but onActivityResult function is not calling to display card number and Expiry date.

My code is as follow

```
import io.card.payment.CardIOActivity;
import io.card.payment.CreditCard;
import org.my.scanExample.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyScanActivity extends Activity
{
// You MUST register with card.io to get an app token. Go to https://card.io/apps/new/
private static final String MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN = "0ac6f74xxxxxxxbefe74e92c7eca"; // My Token number

final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private Button scanButton;
private TextView resultTextView;

private int MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 100; // arbitrary int

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

    resultTextView.setText("card.io library version: " + CardIOActivity.sdkVersion() + "\nBuilt: " + CardIOActivity.sdkBuildDate());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (CardIOActivity.canReadCardWithCamera(this)) {
        scanButton.setText("Scan a credit card with card.io");
    }
    else {
        scanButton.setText("Enter credit card information");
    }
}

public void onScanPress(View v) {
    // This method is set up as an onClick handler in the layout xml
    // e.g. android:onClick="onScanPress"

    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);

    // required for authentication with card.io
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN);

    // customize these values to suit your needs.
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: true
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_ZIP, false); // default: false

    // hides the manual entry button
    // if set, developers should provide their own manual entry mechanism in the app
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); // default: false

    // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

// Here OnActivityResult is not called.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String resultStr;
    if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
        CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

        // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
        resultStr = "Card Number: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

        // Do something with the raw number, e.g.:
        // myService.setCardNumber( scanResult.cardNumber );

        if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
            resultStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n"; 
        }

        if (scanResult.cvv != null) { 
            // Never log or display a CVV
            resultStr += "CVV has " + scanResult.cvv.length() + " digits.\n";
        }

        if (scanResult.zip != null) {
            resultStr += "Zip: " + scanResult.zip + "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        resultStr = "Scan was canceled.";
    }
    resultTextView.setText(resultStr);

}
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed it but I dont see anything wrong with the code. The problem may be in your XML so I thought I would make it easy for you. Send the user to another activity when the scan is completed. Copy this in the appropriate place. Create a new xml.file and see if this works. If you have any problems tell me. This is working fine for me.

```
private Button scanButton;    

}                   
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();


if (CardIOActivity.canReadCardWithCamera(this)) {
scanButton.setText("Charge");
}
else {
scanButton.setText("Charge");
}
}
final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private int MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 100; // arbitrary int            


public void onScanPress(View v) {
// This method is set up as an onClick handler in the layout xml
// e.g. android:onClick="onScanPress"

Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);                 

// required for authentication with card.io
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN);
//Talking points
// customize these values to suit your needs.
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: true
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_ZIP, false); // default: false

// hides the manual entry button
// if set, developers should provide their own manual entry mechanism in the app
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); // default: false

// MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

String resultStr;
if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

// Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()   ,FYI-getRedactedCardNumber displays partial number.
resultStr = "Card: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

// Do something with the raw number, e.g.:
// myService.setCardNumber( scanResult.cardNumber );

if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {


final TextView xx =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.storeview);
String twox = xx.getText().toString();


Intent intent= new Intent(MyScanActivity.this,WhateverNewActivityYouWant.class)
//Adds the redacted card number
.putExtra("Card Number",resultStr)
startActivity(intent);
finish();


resultStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n"; 
}
if (scanResult.cvv != null) { 
// Never log or display a CVV
resultStr += "CVV has " + scanResult.cvv.length() + " digits.\n";
}
if (scanResult.zip != null) {
resultStr += "Zip: " + scanResult.zip + "\n";
}
}
else {
resultStr = "Scan was canceled.";
}
resultTextView.setTag(resultStr);




    }}
```

In your WhateverNewActivityYouWant.class you want to use intent so

```
Intent iscool = getIntent();
    if (iscool.getCharSequenceExtra("Card Number") != null) {
    final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    setmsg.setText(iscool.getCharSequenceExtra("Card Number"));             
    }
```

whatevernewactivityyouwant.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Thanks. My code worked for me. Problem is with camera quality and brightness.